# Where have I visited?

Tags: wordplay, geography, literature

Now an entry into Fortnightly Topic Challenge #41: Short and Sweet

Having a new try on "where do I want to go next" questions", hope you enjoy it.

I have visited:

> 1: Regulations on the internet in an adventure
>
> 2: A shirt for sports I just bought
>
> 3: A part of the former USSR **or** What's that always-learning monkey called?
>
> 4: Better put them together or it will be parted by me
>
> 5: That classic rhyme with "nd" instead of a m
>
> 6: That girl up there with the marbles, I hate that beldam, misread and misread
>
> 7: 6 in a more down-to-earth sense
>
> 8: Put a fresh r in the middle of the middle of an egg, and discard the last bit
>
> 9: Going on the wrong road on the isle
>
> 10: Weighing a vectors of booleans
>
> 11: Half the virtue Harry Potter’s wife should have
>
> 12: Oh, where’s Morgan, and the shack in the creek?

P.S. I am not aware of any typos.

P.P.S. Please tell me what I could improve on, thanks!

Bonus question: What do all these places have in common?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1: Regulations on the internet in an adventure

> E-law in a Dare yields **Delaware**.

2: A shirt for sports I just bought

> From @WAF: **New Jersey**.

3: A part of the former USSR or What's that always-learning monkey called?

> The republic of (and the state of) [Curious] **Georgia**.

4: Better put them together or it will be parted by me

> Connect, or I cut: **Connecticut**.

5: That classic rhyme with "nd" instead of a m

> From @WAF: **Maryland**.

6: That girl up there with the marbles, I hate that beldam, misread and misread

> From @WAF: **North Carolina**.

7: 6 in a more down-to-earth sense

> From @WAF: **South Carolina**.

8: Put a fresh r in the middle of the middle of an egg, and discard the last bit

> From @WAF: **New York**.

9: Going on the wrong road on the isle

> Rode the island...**Rhode Island**.

10: Weighing a vectors of booleans

> We need to mass a choose set — **Massachusetts**

11: Half the virtue Harry Potter’s wife should have

> Harry Potter’s wife is Ginny, so combined with half of the virgin virtue we get Vir + Ginny-a **Virginia**.

12: Oh, where’s Morgan, and the shack in the creek?

> This is a Magic Tree House reference, and Jack and Annie are from Frog Creek, **Pennsylvania**.

Bonus:

> All of these places you have visited are US states which were part of the original 13 colonies. This means that you’re going to the 13th colony next, which is **New Hampshire**.

Comment: @OmegaKrypton how do the rest of these look?

Comment: Not sure about 1 & 12 still, but updated 2 & 4. What do you mean by “add oil”, @OmegaKrypton?

Comment: Updated and upvoted, @OmegaKrypton!

Comment: Depending on the answer to 12, I’d imagine Florida, or Maine....? @OmegaKrypton

Comment: Oh &$%*}€ I even read that series as a kid!!! @OmegaKrypton

Comment: Think I got it now, @OmegaKrypton

Comment: WELL DONE! You've got it!